# Installing Mongo c and c++ drivers in Docker

Tags: docker, mongo-cxx-driver, mongo-c-driver

I'm attempting to install the mongocxx driver in a Docker container, and step number one is to install the mongo-c driver using package manager. My slimmed down Dockerfile:

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:latest
RUN apt-get install -y libmongoc-1.0-0
```

After this step I should be ready to install the cxx driver by following the instructions here: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/installation/

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver.git  --branch releases/stable --depth 1
WORKDIR /mongo-cxx-driver/build
RUN cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
RUN make EP_mnmlstc_core
RUN make && make install
```

This proceeds until the cmake step fails, unable to find the libbson package

```
Step 17/25 : RUN cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
 ---> Running in ba6033b680bb
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Checking for module 'libbson-1.0>=1.5.0'
--   
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:367 (message):
  A required package was not found
```

If I try searching for the libmongoc-1.0 and libbson-1.0 packages using pkg-config it's almost as if nothing was installed from the mongo-c driver.

```
Step 17/26 : RUN pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongoc-1.0 libbson-1.0
 ---> Running in 343f3b4feb3b
Package libmongoc-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libmongoc-1.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libmongoc-1.0' found
Package libbson-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libbson-1.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libbson-1.0' found
```

Has anyone had the experience of installing in a Docker instance? Any insight to what is going wrong here?

Comment: Have you successfully built the C driver and then mongocxx *outside* of a docker container? I'd first validate that your procedure works.

Comment: See dockerfile mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54967860/static-linking-mongocxx-missing-sasl

Answer (score 7):

Below works well for building my docker image.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get -y update \
    && apt-get -y upgrade

RUN apt-get install -y \
    openssh-server \
    g++ \
    cmake \
    git 

#installing the mongoc dependencies and driver
RUN apt-get install -y \
    pkg-config \
    libssl-dev \
    libsasl2-dev

RUN cd ~ \
    && wget https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/releases/download/1.6.2/mongo-c-driver-1.6.2.tar.gz \
    && tar xzf mongo-c-driver-1.6.2.tar.gz \
    && cd mongo-c-driver-1.6.2 \
    && ./configure --disable-automatic-init-and-cleanup \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && cd ~ \
    && rm mongo-c-driver-1.6.2.tar.gz \
    && rm -rf mongo-c-driver-1.6.2

#installing mongocxx driver - connects c++ to mongo
RUN cd ~ \
    && wget https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/archive/r3.1.1.tar.gz \
    && tar -xzf r3.1.1.tar.gz \
    && cd mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.1/build \
    && cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local .. \
    && make EP_mnmlstc_core \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && cd ~ \
    && rm r3.1.1.tar.gz \
    && rm -rf mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.1
```

Comment: The versions are old and the libmongoc build is slightly different but still very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Right after I wrote that comment, I think I spotted the error in your procedure. You are installing the "runtime" package, not the development package. Try installing libmongoc-dev and libbson-dev. Those should provide the needed header files and SONAME symlinks such that you can build the C++ driver.